# Convert unusual string into date time

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have a system that outputs dates in the format "1{yy}{MM}{dd}" and I am trying to find a good way to parse it back into a real date.
At the moment I am using this:

```
  var value = "1110825";
  var z = Enumerable.Range(1,3).Select(i => int.Parse(value.Substring(i, 2))).ToList();
  var d = new DateTime(2000 + z[0], z[1], z[2]);
```

but I'm sure there's a cleaner/more efficient way to do it?

I've tried DT.ParseExact, but can't find a suitable format string to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var value = "1110825";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "1yyMMdd",
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
}
```

(You may want to use `TryParseExact` of course, if you need to cope with invalid data in any way other than with an exception.)

A slight variation of this is the format pattern of "'1'yyMMdd" - note the apostrophes round the 1. That quotes the 1 to force it to be treated as a "literal" in the pattern. It's not important in this case, but if you actually had values such as "y110825" then you'd want to quote the `y` to make sure it wasn't treated as part of a year specifier.

Comment: aha!  It was the "1" I was missing from my format string...I was searching for a "ignore" character of somekind.

Answer (score 1):

you can use DateTime.ParseExact:

here is a example for 12/26/1979:

```
    var parseback = DateTime.ParseExact("1791226", "1yyMMdd",
                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Comment: If I answer something and I see someone wrote what I wrote earlier, I delete my answer.

Comment: Stop moaning, clearly you got 2 upvotes and the net gain is 18 points... If you really want I can remove it, but what is 2 points?

Comment: @leppie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2849/discussion-between-ckoenig-and-leppie)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact(string s, string format, IFormatProvider provider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

an example

```
DateTime.ParseExact("1110825", "1yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: duplicate without explanation

Comment: @Dr.Snail what explanation do you believe is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code

> ```
> using System;
> using System.Collections.Generic;
> using System.ComponentModel;
> using System.Data;
> using System.Drawing;
> using System.Text;
> using System.Windows.Forms;
>
> namespace DateTimeConvert
> {
>     public partial class Form1 : Form
>     {
>         public Form1()
>         {
>             InitializeComponent();
>         }
>
>         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>           label1.Text= ConvDate_as_str(textBox1.Text);
>         }
>
>         public string ConvDate_as_str(string dateFormat)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 char[] ch = dateFormat.ToCharArray();
>                 string[] sps = dateFormat.Split(' ');
>                 string[] spd = sps[0].Split('.');
>                 dateFormat = spd[0] + ":" + spd[1]+" "+sps[1];
>                 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>                 dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFormat);
>                 return dt.Hour.ToString("00") + dt.Minute.ToString("00");
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 return "Enter Correct Format like <5.12 pm>";
>             }
>
>         }
>
>
>         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>            label2.Text = ConvDate_as_date(textBox2.Text);
>         }
>
>         public string ConvDate_as_date(string stringFormat)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 string hour = stringFormat.Substring(0, 2);
>                 string min = stringFormat.Substring(2, 2);
>                 DateTime dt = new DateTime();
>                 dt = Convert.ToDateTime(hour+":"+min);
>                 return String.Format("{0:t}", dt); ;
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>                 return "Please Enter Correct format like <0559>";
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```